# Remove Excess space between th and td Elements

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am using a table to display data .I am trying to remove space from the left and right of th and td element.

I have tried checking on stack overflow and other places but they all remove vertical spaces between cells. What i want to remove is remove space from left and right.

```css
  #contact_search{
    border-collapse: collapse;

  }
  #contact_search tr td, #contact_search tr th{
    /* text-align: center; */
    border: 1px solid #006;
    line-height: 1;
  }
```

```html
<table id="contact_search" > 
    <thead>
        <tr>        
            <th>Nametest</th>  
            <th>Country</th> 
            <th>City</th> 
            <th>Category</th> 
            <th>Work</th>  
            <th>Mobile</th>  
            <th>Email</th>  
            <th>Trades</th>  
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>Australia</td>
        <td>Auckland</td>
        <td>Corporate Client</td>
        <td>3275020</td>
        <td>9926104</td>
        <td>johndoe@example.com</td>
        <td>None</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what i get 
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLsKJ.png)

The red circle is what i want to remove.

Comment: I moved this into the snippet tool (without any edits), but the issue isn't replicated. Possibly a browser difference, or prior edits didn't refresh promptly(?).

Comment: The output seems alright. No extra space!

Comment: Please Have a look at the image

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry about the problem you are experiencing but I cant see it from my end. I wrote a new html file and copied your contents without any edits into it like you can see below but the issue was not detected. You too can try out and see for yourself.

```css
#contact_search{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
  #contact_search tr td, #contact_search tr th{
  /* text-align: center; */
  border: 1px solid #006;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<table id="contact_search" > 
  <thead>
      <tr>                                
          <th>Nametest</th>  
          <th>Country</th> 
          <th>City</th> 
          <th>Category</th> 
          <th>Work</th>  
          <th>Mobile</th>  
          <th>Email</th>  
          <th>Trades</th>  
       </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>Australia</td>
      <td>Auckland</td>
      <td>Corporate Client</td>
      <td>3275020</td>
      <td>9926104</td>
      <td>johndoe@example.com</td>
      <td>None</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Possible reasons include:

1. browser issue (try to use a different browser, clear history on your browser)
2. you never saved your edits
3. your css has table attribute already added to it at the top making browser inherit them hence ignoring those for #contact_search

You could try out this for yourself in your css by the way

```
#contact_search{
    border-collapse: collapse!important;

  }
  #contact_search tr td, #contact_search tr th{
    /* text-align: center; */
    border: 1px solid #006!important;
    line-height: 1!important;
  }
```

please note the keyword **!important** for css for overriding attributes.

Comment: Teach a noob about important. The cancer of CSS. Fix your CSS do not use important.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox, use the [Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector). This way you can see which css attribute influences the table elements. For other browsers there should be similar possibilities.

See e.g. for [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/), [Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS causing the padding is not included in your example. Run this snippet and look at the output. Other CSS you are importing is causing the table width.

In Chrome, right click on one of the table cells and go inspect. Look at the styles in the devtools to see where it is coming from.

```css
  #contact_search{
    border-collapse: collapse;

  }
  #contact_search tr td, #contact_search tr th{
    /* text-align: center; */
    border: 1px solid #006;
    line-height: 1;
  }
```

```html
<table id="contact_search" > 
    <thead>
        <tr>                                
            <th>Nametest</th>  
            <th>Country</th> 
            <th>City</th> 
            <th>Category</th> 
            <th>Work</th>  
            <th>Mobile</th>  
            <th>Email</th>  
            <th>Trades</th>  
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>Australia</td>
        <td>Auckland</td>
        <td>Corporate Client</td>
        <td>3275020</td>
        <td>9926104</td>
        <td>johndoe@example.com</td>
        <td>None</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```